# Legend title not displayed in ggplot-maps

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, legend, title

As soon as I add a dynamic range for my legend labels within the scale_fill_distiller-option, I get only a "1" instead the defined legend title within labs(fill="title"). What do I have to change?

Here is my code:

```
map <- ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data=data, aes(fill=Count_Number)) +
  labs(title="Chart Title", 
       x="",y="") +
  labs(colour = "Legend Title") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette ="RdBu", direction = -1, na.value="#ffffff", 
                       range(c(min(data$Count_Number, na.rm=T),max(data$Count_Number,na.rm=T))), 
                       breaks = seq(min(data$Count_Number, na.rm=T),max(data$Count_Number, na.rm=T),by=2)) +  
  theme_opts +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=12, face="bold")) +  
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(legend.key.width=unit(2,"cm")) +
  theme(legend.title=element_text(size=11)) +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm")) +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(
    data = gmddata_covid,
    aes(label = Case, geometry = geometry),
    stat = "sf_coordinates",
    min.segment.length = 0,
    color = "#333333",
    segment.color = "white",
    size = 2.5
  )
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I think you want `range = c(min(` instead of `range(c(min(`

Comment: Try writing out the argument name for the values you are passing via `range()`.  Maybe this is supposed to be passed to the `values` argument?  If you take a look at the documentation for `scale_fill_distiller()` you'll see `...` comes before the named arguments in the function and so I believe you ended up passing the range to the `name` argument instead of whatever argument you were hoping to pass it to.

Comment: While you mention that you're using `labs(fill="title")` in your question, the code you posted has `labs(colour="Legend Title")`.  Since there's no `colour` aesthetic applied, you would not see that title.  The aesthetic mapped in `aes()` is `fill`, so you should just change `labs(colour="Legend Title")` to `labs(fill="Legend Title")`.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Removing the range-part was the solution. And of course change labs(colour=...) to labs(fill=...).